# Has the differential equation $ A'(t) \times adj (A(t)) = M(t)$ already been studied?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-system

Consider a continuous and locally integrable matrix $M:t\mapsto M(t) \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}(\mathbb{R} \mbox{ or } \mathbb{C})$

I want to find a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $A:t\mapsto A(t) \in GL_n^+(\mathbb{R}) \mbox{ or } GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying

$$ A'(t) \times adj (A(t)) = M(t)$$

where $ A'$ is the usual derivative of $A$ and $adj(A(t))$ is the adjugate matrix of $A(t)$, that is to say the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Of course such a function might not always exist.

Has this problem already been studied ? If so, what kind of reference should I consult ?

If such a problem has not been studied yet, hopefully we can still come up with a solution for $n=2$

Comment: Well, at least one can obtain $\det(A(t))=\int_{t_0}^t\operatorname{tr}(M(t))dt+\det(A(t_0))$ by Jacobi's formula and rewrite the equation as $A'(t)=\frac{M(t)A(t)}{\det(A(t))}$.

Comment: true, I found this bit by myself a few hours ago !